# Are updates to outdated but still working links discouraged

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Recently I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073349/3959259) answer and followed the link to an article from Jon Skeet which pointed to his no longer active blog. Since I'm a frequent reader of his blog I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13671878) the link to point to the right one. The edit was rejected giving the reason

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

It was just after that rejection that I realized that an other user had edited the same link just a day before because it was broken. Probably that was also a cause for the rejection.

My question now is: was my edit justified or should I update links only when they are broken?

Comment: I don't get the "or should I update links only when they are broken" part of your question. The link WAS broken, wasn't it?

Comment: @Gimby No, it wasn't broken, it just pointed to a blog which is no longer maintained under this address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your edit was fine, especially since it wasn't on one of Jon's answers and the author might not have been aware of the change in Jon's blog location.  Had it been one of Jon's answers, the update would have probably been still ok, but I personally would have left a comment for Jon first.

In my opinion, the edit rejection was a bad review by the reviewers, but could have been avoided if you had a better edit comment. All you wrote was

> Updated Link - again

While anyone reviewing should have clicked the links to see why you were updating the URL, you cannot count reviewers actually doing that.  It also depends on which "view" the reviewer is using.  If they are using the "Rendered View" instead of the markdown view, changes to links are less obvious.  Again, reviewers should have checked the links but you can't count on them doing that.  Every little bit you can do to make it more obvious to the reviewers why you are doing something, the better luck you will have.

If you expanded the comment, specifically to say why you were updating the link.  Something like the following would have been perfectly clear why.

> Updating link to point to same article on Jon's current blog since the old one is no longer maintained.

Overly brief comments when it isn't perfectly clear why you are doing something without more research is going to have a lower success rate, so I always believe you should try to hit the reviewers over the head to make them understand why approving the edit makes the post better.